# Host website on new gTLD?

Tags: dns

With the new gTLDs being opened up (let's use .example as an example) is it possible to host a website at http://example ? Or does there still need to be a 2nd level (e.g. http://something.example)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's technically possible, but some people may have problems because some systems treat a host name without *any* dots in it as being a local name instead of a DNS name.

Indeed, a few smaller ccTLDs already have `A` records at their apex.

Answer (score 0):

It wont be possible.. even for brand gTLD.

.example --> TLD
you need domain.example to set an host